# VBA Adjustment for adaptablity

Tags: web, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

I have this code I would like to rewrite to get the Bid price from yahoo.  The code currently gets the Last price, however I would like to get the Bid price and if the Bid price is zero, then get the last price.  I tried exhaustively to rewrite it myself but was not successful.  Can someone assist in my quest to rewrite this code.

Thank you kindly

```
Sub GetRate()
    Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim htmlDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim URL As String
    Dim HTMLspans As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLspan As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    URL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAP181221C00170000?p=AAP181221C00170000"

    XMLPage.Open "GET", URL, False
    XMLPage.send

    htmlDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText

    Set HTMLspans = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("span")

    For Each HTMLspan In HTMLspans
        If HTMLspan.className = "Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" Then
            debug.Print HTMLspan.innerText
        End If
    Next HTMLspan

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. It should fetch you the bid price if it is greater than 0 otherwise it will grab you the last price:

```
Sub GetRate()
    Const Url$ = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAP181221C00170000?p=AAP181221C00170000"
    Dim S$, elem As Object, post As Object

    With New XMLHTTP60
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .send
        S = .responseText
    End With

    With New HTMLDocument
        .body.innerHTML = S

        Set elem = .querySelector("td[data-test='BID-value'] > span")
        If elem.innerText = 0 Then
            Set post = .querySelector("#quote-market-notice").ParentNode.FirstChild
            MsgBox post.innerText
        Else: MsgBox elem.innerText
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Exactly the way you have tried above other than `.querySelector()`:

```
Sub GetRate()
    Const Url$ = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAP181221C00170000?p=AAP181221C00170000"
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Htmldoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim elem As Object, post As Object

    With Http
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .send
        Htmldoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Set elem = Htmldoc.querySelector("td[data-test='BID-value'] > span")
    If elem.innerText = 0 Then
        Set post = Htmldoc.querySelector("#quote-market-notice").ParentNode.FirstChild
        MsgBox post.innerText
    Else: MsgBox elem.innerText
    End If
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
Microsoft xml,v6.0
Microsoft Html Object Library
```

If you wanna learn how `.querySelector()` works, check out [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Comment: I sincerely thank you for assisting my request.  If I may ask some question as I'm still a novice in vba,  What are the lines below accomplish?

With New HTMLDocument
        .body.innerHTML = S

        Set elem = .querySelector("td[data-test='BID-value'] > span")
        If elem.innerText = 0 Then
            Set post = .querySelector("#quote-market-notice").ParentNode.FirstChild

Comment: Check out the edit @Anthony. The way you have targeted the class name in your script is error prone as they are compound class names and most probably dynamic and as a result the script will fail miserably when you try few days from now.

Comment: is there a way to speed up the code?

In my code I posted, I modified it to use with multiple rows (10-rows only),  However, when I implemented this new code, it runs significantly slower.  I really appreciated your help; I was curious if the code could run faster.  Comparing the two codes, there is a significant speed difference.  Thanks you for your help.

Comment: Did you try wrapping the script within `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` block to see the performance?

Comment: Yes...I've already tried your suggestion.  Including Enable Events = False, and Manual Calculation